# Warum spricht man bei Bildschirmen von "Auflösung"?

Tags: etymology

Auflösen ist mir nur im chemischen Sinne bekannt. 
Wieso verwendet man es bei Ausdrücken wie "Der Bildschirm hat eine Auflösung von.." oder "Das Spielt hat eine gute Auflösung"?

Comment: Es könnte eine Adaption des englischen Wortes "resolution" sein. Zudem wird "Auflösung" auch z.B. im Sinne von "Messauflösung" (cf.  "Resolve the following improper fraction into partial fractions") verwendet. "auf" + "lösen" => etwas Verworrenes entwirren, sodass die einzelnen Teile erkennbar werden. Höhere Auflösung => mehr einzelne Teile (Pixel).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Der Begriff war bereits in der analogen Fotografie üblich. Damals hat man von "Linienpaaren" gesprochen, d. h. man hat eine Fläche mit parallelen Linien fotografiert und geschaut, ab wann zwei nebeneinander liegende Linien zu einer verschmelzen. Ich vermute mal, dass sich Auflösung daher gebildet hat, dass zwei verschmolzene Linien bei einem besseren Film zu zwei Linien "auflösen"; und dies ist ja auch die sonstige Verwendung von "auflösen": Wenn sich eine Demo oder ein Stück Würfelzucker auflösen, wird eine Einheit zu einer Anzahl kleinerer Teile. Das Auflösungsvermögen wird auch in Bogensekunden angegeben: wenn man einen optischen Apparat auf eine Fläche richtet, die Länge X entfernt ist, so kann man sich einen Bogen denken, der über die Fläche streicht und dabei einen bestimmten Winkelabstand noch auflösen, also als getrennte Einheiten wahrnehmen kann.

Hinsichtlich des Bildschirms können 1920 × 1080 bei gleicher Größe und gleichem Sichtabstand mehr Details auflösen als 320 × 200 (wenn ich einen 24"-Bildschirm mit 1920 × 1080 direkt am Auge kleben habe, nutzen mir die 1920 × 1080 herzlich wenig).

Answer (score -3):

Ich gehe davon aus, dass man in diesem Zusammenhang *Auflösung* sagt, da hierbei die Größe eines Bildes (Beispiel: 4608x3072px) "aufgelöst" wird in **eine** Einheit, nämlich die Auflösung (~14,2MP). Daher werden zwei Angaben in eine aufgelöst.

Comment: Das halte ich für sehr abwegig. Zum einen ist auch *4608×3072* eine Auflösung. Zum anderen wird der Begriff auch sehr ähnlich in Fällen verwendet in denen die Anzahl der Zahlen nicht reduziert wird, z. B.: »Diese digitale Waage hat eine Auflösung von 100 g.«

Comment: Auflösung im Zusammenhang mit (Digital-)Waagen habe ich um ehrlich zu sein noch nie gehört. Trotz dessen hast du wohl Recht, aber das war das Erste was mir in dem Zusammenhang in den Sinn kam.